# Probability of picking a certain sequence of balls from a box

Tags: probability

I have 4 balls in a box, three are red, one is white.

The probability of picking r,r,r,w is 0.75 * 0.75 * 0.75 * 0.25 = 0.105

Surely there are 4 different possible arrangements:

rrrw
rrwr
rwrr
wrrr

But if the probability of each combination is 0.105, the sum of the probabilities is only 0.42.

Surely the sum should add up to 1, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The probability you give for $r,r,r,w$ is correct if you are putting each ball back before drawing the next. In this case it is possible to draw $w,w,w,w$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pick 4 balls, with replacement, you will get exactly $k$ of these balls to be white, where $k$ is some element in set $S = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Your computation of $(0.42)$ represents the probability of the 4 picks resulting in $k = 1$, re the above paragraph.

In order to get a total probability of $1$, you would also have to consider the $4$ other possible values from set $S$.